# Object doesn't support this property or method - Excel Workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I know this subject showed up many times but each issue is different and other topics didn't helped me resolve my problem.

Trying to close files which were already opened by other macro:

```
 Do While Cells(c, 1) <> ""
        wb1 = Workbooks(Cells(c, 1) & " Daily " & Format(Date, "dd mmm yy")   & ".xls")
        wb2 = Workbooks(Cells(c, 1) & " .xls")
        If wb1 <> "" And wb2 <> "" Then
            'Windows(Cells(c, 1) & " Daily " & Format(Date, "dd mmm yy") & ".xls").Activate
            wb1.Close Savechanges:=True
            'Windows(Cells(c, 1) & " .xls").Activate
            wb2.Close Savechanges:=True
        End If

    c = c + 1
Loop
```

cells(c,1) is column with names of the clients.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: WHere is the error ?  I think you need to check "not wb1 is nothing"

Comment: error is in second line wb1 = ... Name of file is good because it works when I use Windows(...).Acivate.
Tried to use just Windows(...).Close SaveChanges:True but error Object...

Answer (score 1):

The `Workbooks` collection returns a `Workbook` object. When you want to assign an object reference to a variable you need to use `Set`:

```
Set wb1 = Workbooks(Cells(c, 1) & " Daily " & Format(Date, "dd mmm yy")   & ".xls")
Set wb2 = Workbooks(Cells(c, 1) & " .xls")
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks!